# Making request to API using python

Tags: python, rest, http-proxy

I have created and API using python+flask. When is try to hit the api using postman or chrome it works fine and I am able to get to the api.

On the other hand when I try to use python

```
import requests
requests.get("http://localhost:5050/")
```

I get 407. I guess that the proxy of the our environment is not allowing me to hit the localhost. But due to LAN settings in IE/Chrome the request went through.

I did try to set proxies , auth in request and now I start getting 502(bad gateway). If I see on the API side I can't see a request come through. What can I do to troubleshoot the same.

Comment: Try use 127.0.0.1:5050 instead http url.

Comment: I think you need to provide some header which are missing

Comment: Are you able to access it in your browser?

Comment: yes @DhKo i am able to access via browser

Answer (score 1):

According to [requests module documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) you can either provide proxy details through environment variable **HTTP_PROXY** (in case use Linux distribution):

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY="http://corporate-proxy:port"
$ python
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://localhost:5050/')
```

Or provide **proxies** keyword argument to get method directly:

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://coporate-proxy:port',
}

requests.get('http://localhost:5050/', proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import requests
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
requests.get("http://localhost:5050/")
```